# Find NOT matching characters in a string with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If Im able to check a string if there are invalid characters:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[^A-Z]$");
string myString = "SOMEString"; 
if (r.IsMatch(myString)) 
{     
  Console.WriteLine("invalid string!");
}
```

it is fine. But what I would like to print out every invalid character in this string? Like in the example **SOMEString** => invalid chars are t,r,i,n,g. Any ideas?

Comment: The example you brought would be invalid for any string with more than one character. It might not be exactly what you're trying to ask. Did you mean `[^A-Z]+$`?

Comment: Why do you use Regex for such a simple case? Isn't `var invalidChars = "SOMEString".Where(c => !char.IsUpper(c)).ToArray();` enough?

Comment: @JNF: It would actually only match the last character of the string and not care what the rest is (ie `SOMEStrinG` would be valid by the above). Its not anchored at the beginning, only the end. Your one would only match strings were *all* characters are invalid. Most likely what is needed is `[^A-Z]` since that would match any invalid character in the string.

Comment: @L.B: Bear in mind the example above may have been simplified (ie that isn't the actual regex being used).

Comment: @Chris, my mistake, forgot how `IsMatch` works... ;)

Comment: @L.B thank you thats a good idea. But my simple regex was just ONE example :) Im using a more complex one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LINQ. Following will give you an array of 5 elements, not matching to the regex.

```
char[] myCharacterArray = myString.Where(c => r.IsMatch(c.ToString())).ToArray();
foreach (char c in myCharacterArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Output will be:

```
t
r
i
n
g
```

EDIT:

It looks like, you want to treat all lower case characters as invalid string. You may try:

```
   char[] myCharacterArray2 = myString
                                   .Where(c => ((int)c) >= 97 && ((int)c) <= 122)
                                   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example the regex would succeed on one character since it's looking for the last character if it isn't uppercase, and your string has such a character.

The regex should be changed to `Regex r = new Regex("[^A-Z]");`.

(updated following @Chris's comments)

However, for your purpose the regex is actually what you want - just use `Matches`.

e.g.:

```
foreach (Match item in r.Matches(myString))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ToString() + " is invalid");
}
```

Or, if you want one line:

```
foreach (Match item in r.Matches(myString))
{
   str += item.ToString() + ", ";
}
Console.WriteLine(str + " are invalid");
```

Comment: You'll need to update the regex too - it is currently only checking the last character of the string.

Comment: @Chris, wouldn't it get all matches? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: The problem is the `$` at the end of the regex, not the method used. This anchors it to the end of the string which means that the character matched must be followed by the end of the string. all it needs is removing the `$` to allow it to match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Output will be `tring are invalid`

Comment: @VishalSuthar, rather `t,r,i,n,g, are invalid`. That's what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vishal Suthar: I've run the code and get `t, r, i, n, g,  are invalid
`. I'm not sure how you don't get the commas on the single line version... Maybe the regex edit caused it to work correctly after all...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
char[] list = new char[5];
Regex r = new Regex("[^A-Z]*$");
string myString = "SOMEString";

foreach (Match match in r.Matches(myString))
{
    list = match.Value.ToCharArray();
    break;
}

string str = "invalid chars are ";
foreach (char ch in list)
{
    str += ch + ", ";
}

Console.Write(str);
```

**OUTPUT: `invalid chars are t, r, i, n, g`**

Comment: You'll need to update the regex too - it is currently only checking the last character of the string.